# how to filter data in include 'model' using strongloop

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop

I am trying to join table `ABC` with `XYZ`, and to filter data of included table 'xyz' using **Strongloop**.

*My code is:*

```
 return ABC.find({filter:{ 
                    where: {abcPropertyName: {neq: '1234'}}, 
                    include: {**XYZ**: *[{xyzPropertyName: 'somevalue'}]*}}}).$promise
```

*My data-source is:*

____abc.json____

```
"relations": {
    "xyz": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "xyz",
      "foreignKey": "abcId"
    }
```

____xyz.json____

```
"relations": {
    "abc": {
      "type": "blongsTo",
      "model": "abc",
      "foreignKey": "abcId"
    }
```

---

**Issue:** filter in 'xyz' is not working. Please help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following include filter:

```
include: { 
    relation: **XYZ**, 
    scope: {
      where: {xyzPropertyName: 'somevalue'} 
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter#Includefilter-Includewithfilters)